# IE8 | Not an object error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

On IE8 (not on IE9 or Safari) I get an error

```
this.text_array is null or not an object
```

for this line

```
`if( this.text_array[element].value === '' )`
```

for this object -

```
/**
 *          JClass - Text
 */

var Text = function( form_name ) 
{
    this.text_array = document.forms[form_name].elements;
};

Text.prototype.patterns = 
{
    prefix_url:     /^(http:)|(https:)\/\//,
    url:            /^.{1,2048}$/,
    tweet:          /^.{1,40}$/, 
    title:          /^.{1,32}$/, 
    name:           /^.{1,64}$/, 
    email:          /^.{1,64}@.{1,255}$/,
    pass:           /^.{6,20}$/
};

Text.prototype.checkPattern = function( type ) 
{
    return this.patterns[type].exec( this.text_array[type].value );
};

Text.prototype.checkUrlAdd = function( type ) 
{
    return this.patterns[type].exec( this.text_array.url.value );
};  

Text.prototype.checkSameEmail = function() 
{
    return ( (this.text_array.email.value) === (this.text_array.email1.value) );
};

Text.prototype.checkEmpty = function() 
{
    var element;
    for ( element in this.text_array )
    {
        if( this.text_array[element].value === '' ) 
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
};
```

Not sure where to begin troubleshooting this.  I guess I could start by hard coding the element object...that would eliminate the DOM Pull as a suspect.  I could continue in this way...but I don't have IE8 available right now.  Trial and Error unless someone has a bit of insight.

**Related SO**

[for in vs. for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays/500531#500531)

Comment: How are you calling `checkEmpty`? Keep in mind that `this` can bind to something other than the `Text` instance, depending on how you call it. Or maybe `document.forms[form_name].elements` really is `null` but I'm _sure_ you checked that ;)

Comment: checked by correlation...but that would be my first guess as well.

Comment: Note that `for..in` iterates properties, not just indexes. Use simple `for` loops to iterate Array indexes. Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/a/500531/15031

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start your debugging, use `console.log(this.text_array);` in relevant places.

I can only assume it's caused by `this` not being set right by the browser. In this case, start your `checkEmpty` function with `var that = this;` and use `that` instead of `this` through it.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up using

> document.getElementById()

for form access as a quick solution to fix the problem.  Did not have time to troubleshoot further per suggestions.

Comment: To make this a proper answer, you should give the full details of the solution, i.e. show that you used document.getElementById instead of document.forms[form_name].